# How to dynamically create object names based on a list?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class FoodDetails which accepts a list of names

```
class FoodDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  FoodDetails({this.namesList});

  final List namesList;

  @override
  State<FoodDetails> createState() => FoodDetailsState();
}
```

I want to create objects of a class **NameClass** based on the names of namesList.
For example:
If `namesList=["John", "Doe"];`
I want to create lists like

```
List<NameClass> John;
List<NameClass> Doe;
```

How can I achieve this? I tried the following but it doesn't work

```
class FoodDetailsState extends State<FoodDetails> {
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    for (int i = 0; i < widget.namesList.length; i++) {
      List<NameClass> widget.namesList[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't.  This isn't JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create objects dynamically like `javascript` in `dart`.

Easy workaround would be using `HashMap` in which the key will be the desired dynamically allocated name and the value will be the instance of the object.

Code snippet which would help you start with this:

```
import 'dart:collection';

class Class {
  String? var1;
  String? var2;
  Class({var1, var2}) {
    this.var1 = var1;
    this.var2 = var2;
  }
}

void main() {
  var list = ["John", "Doe"];
  HashMap<String, Class> map = new HashMap();

  list.forEach((element) {
    map.addAll({element: new Class()}); // Just adding the key to the Map
  });

  print(map.containsKey("John"));
  print(map.containsKey("Doe"));

// Can easily manipulate the value known the key
  map["John"]!.var1 = "variable1";
  map["Doe"]!.var2 = "variable2";

  map.forEach((key, value) {
    print("Key: " +
        key +
        " has values var1: " +
        (value.var1 ?? "") +
        " and var2: " +
        (value.var2 ?? ""));
  });
}
```

The output would be:

```
true
true
Key: John has values var1: variable1 and var2:
Key: Doe has values var1:  and var2: variable2
```